# Как работать с YouTube API на React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-api

Подскажите пожалуйста как работать с YouTube API на React.js.
Нужно реализовать поисковик [с кнопкой!] и результаты нужно выводить на туже
страницу,по умолчанию должно выводиться 12 видео роликов.

Comment: имеется специальный пакет `react-youtube` а полностью скрипт тебе никто писать не будет. У пакета довольно много примеров хороших и уверен уроков по нему полно

Comment: спасибо,нет скрипта не надо писать,нужно какой либо туториал

Comment: @AndreyFreiz также можно делать с Redux ?

Comment: а почему нельзя